# Image processing in android with stretch scale and Twist effect

Tags: android, image, image-processing

Now a day i am doing a project related to image processing with the fallowing feature
1)Stretch 2)Scale 3)Twist
I am not understand how to achieve it in android.
Here i am putting some screen shot related to this project for makeing more clarity in my question.[image]

The above image  is the real image i want to apply image processing over this image for making it like 
blow image.
[image]

Please me any suggestion,help url ,tutorial and other thinks for achieve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a function which, when applied to pixel coordinates, outputs new pixel coordinates producing the twist effect you're looking for.
It may help to take a look at some of the functions listed at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageTransformation.html (esp. the section "Neat examples").

Once you have defined the function, you'd need to implement in Android the equivalent of the `ImageTransformation` command. Basically, for each pixel in the output image, call the function to know where to sample in the input image; use windowing when sampling the input image so that you limit artifacts and get a smoother result.